# Ajax success data show undefind

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I return a array object data Ajax success result then i print li tag but its show undefind

My Ajax code is

```
$.ajax({
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': base_url +'party/selectCities?id='+state, 
        success: function(data) {
            var newData = data.replace(/\"/g, "")
            if(newData == ""){
            }else{
                var datas = JSON.stringify(newData);
                var jsdata = JSON.parse(datas);
                alert(jsdata);
                var html = ``;
                for(var i = 0; i<jsdata.length; i++){    
                    html += '<li ng-click="selectcityclubs(' + jsdata[i].city+ ');>' + jsdata[i].city+ '</li>';
                    }

                    $("#ClubCity").html(html);
            }
        }
});
```

here i **alert the jsdata** i get result like

```
 [{city:North Goa},{city:South Goa}]
```

but the li list show undefind, How to solve this issue..

please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Does your API respond with JSON or not? If not, why not? There should be no need for manual manipulation of response data strings or any extra stringifying / parsing

Comment: @phil its angular 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a double quote after the `ng-click`. Check out this snippet below.

Also utilizing the template literals (backticks) instead of using `+` to concatenate strings helps make things more readable.

EDIT: Updated with Angular and showing how it  can be done with `ng-repeat` versus `plain HTML` and `jQuery`

```js
// angular code
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectcityclubs = function(c) {
      alert(c);
    }

    $scope.jsdata = [{
      city: 'North Goa'
    }, {
      city: 'South Goa'
    }];
  });



// jQuery code 
let jsdata = [{
  city: 'North Goa'
}, {
  city: 'South Goa'
}];

let html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < jsdata.length; i++) {
  html += `<li ng-click="selectcityclubs('${jsdata[i].city}');">${jsdata[i].city}</li>`;
}

$("#ClubCity").html(html);
```

```css
li,
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">
  <h2>Uses jQuery (working)</h2>
  <ul id="ClubCity"></ul>
  <h2>Click Works</h2>
  <ul id="ClubCity1">
    <li><button ng-click="selectcityclubs('North Goa')">North Goa</button></li>
    <li><button ng-click="selectcityclubs('South Goa')">South Goa</button></li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Uses ng-repeat (working)</h2>
  <ul id="ClubCity2">
    <li ng-repeat="city in jsdata" ng-click="selectcityclubs(city.city);">{{city.city}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: ng-click does not work what i do for that

Comment: @code_dev check out my edited answer, I updated it to include angular and if you click the `Run code snippet` button you will see it work.

Comment: ya i will update that but my function not working, it's awesome job

Comment: maybe make a new question that includes more of your code and the function and that could help get you an answer to that part

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518058/ajax-return-data-ng-click-function-not-working  already open that

Comment: Oh cool I posted an answer there if you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes (") for the ng-click attribute and escape the double quotes within it using a backslash ()

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < jsdata.length; i++) {
  html += '<li ng-click="selectcityclubs(\'' + jsdata[i].city + '\')">' + jsdata[i].city + '</li>';
}
$("#ClubCity").html(html);
```

Comment: here the ng-click function does not working why ?

Comment: taking a guess here, have you tried camel case like `selectCityClubs()`

Comment: @treckstar no function write correctly but no responce