# Ajax return data ng-click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I try to pass a data in ajax return and in that data there is function that write in angular 1 ng-click like

```
$.ajax({
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': base_url +'party/selectCities?id='+state, 
        success: function(data) {
            var newData = data.replace(/\"/g, "")
            if(newData == ""){
            }else{
                var jsdata = JSON.parse(data);
                var html = ``;
                $.each(jsdata, function (index, item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    html += '<li onclick="selectcityclubs(\'' + item.city + '\');">' + item.city + '</li>';
                    
                });
                $("#home-city-listing").html(html);
            }
        }
});
```

it show in page normally and i inspect that that also show correctly like.

```
<ul class="partylist ng-scope" id="home-city-listing" ng-controller="clubController">
    <li ng-click="selectcityclubs('Chittoor');">Chittoor</li>
    <li ng-click="selectcityclubs('Cuddapah');">Cuddapah</li>
    <li ng-click="selectcityclubs('East Godavari');">East Godavari</li>
</ul>
```

why that function not working not any response in page and console not show any error, how to solve this issue please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: See new [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dweuc6kL/1/) to see updated answer without jQuery, using only angular**

**Stack Overflow Code should also work now**

Take a look at [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dweuc6kL/) because the StackOverflow code won't run.

Pretty much instead of using `jQuery` to output the `<li>` elements, use `ng-repeat` in the `HTML`.

The code below uses `try/catch` to make the HTML load with 2 cities, because it won't work on JsFiddle/StackOverflow with `ajax`.

If this doesn't work then I'm not sure what your `selectcityclubs` function is doing and might have an error in there.

```js
// setup variables to make code look as close to original
let base_url = '';
let state = 'NorthBoa';
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('clubController', function($scope, $http) {
    // handles the button click
    $scope.selectcityclubs = function(c) {
      console.log('Button clicked: ' + c);
      alert(c);
    }

    $scope.jsdata = [];
    $http.get(base_url + 'party/selectCities?id=' + state)
      .then(function onSuccess(response) {
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(response);
        // make sure you check response.data
        $scope.jsdata = response.data.replace(/\"/g, "");
      })
      .catch(function onError(response) {
        console.log('Error, couldnt access ajax.');
        console.log(response);
        // adding here because we can't get to the AJAX URL
        $scope.jsdata = [{
          city: 'North Goa'
        }, {
          city: 'South Goa'
        }];
      })

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app">
  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/dweuc6kL/1/">Take a look at JsFiddle with updated answer for 1.4.8</a>
  <h2>Using angular 1.7.5</h2>
  <ul class="partylist" id="home-city-listing" ng-controller="clubController">
    <li ng-repeat="city in jsdata" ng-click="selectcityclubs(city.city);">{{city.city}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: city li show empty console data show properly

Comment: I just made an update check out the new [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dweuc6kL/1/).

Comment: i will update the same as not data list li tag its show blank but data return show in network tab

Comment: Are you using `angular 1.7.5` or `1.4.8`? The `JsFiddle` uses `1.4.8`, I updated this answer again to show it working with `1.7.5`.  Pretty much you take out `.success` and `.fail` for `.then()` and `.catch`. Try running the answer above now